# How do I replace the 4th item in a list that is in a file that starts with a particular string?

Tags: python-3.x, file, replace

I need to search for a name in a file and in the line starting with that name, I need to replace the fourth item in the list that is separated my commas. I have began trying to program this with the following code, but I have not got it to work.

```
with open("SampleFile.txt", "r") as f:
  newline=[]
  for word in f.line(): 
      newline.append(word.replace(str(String1), str(String2)))
with open("SampleFile.txt", "w") as f:
  for line in newline :
      f.writelines(line)

  #this piece of code replaced every occurence of String1 with String 2

f = open("SampleFile.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    if line.startswith(Name):
        if line.contains(String1):
            newline = line.replace(str(String1), str(String2))

  #this came up with a syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give some dummy data which would help people to answer your question. I suppose you to backup your data: You can save the edited data to a new file or you can backup the old file to a backup folder before working on the data (think about using "from shutil import copyfile" and then "copyfile(src, dst)"). Otherwise by making a mistake you could easily ruin your data without being able to easily restore them.

You can't replace the string with "newline = line.replace(str(String1), str(String2))"! Think about "strong" as your search term and a line like "Armstrong,Paul,strong,44" - if you replace "strong" with "weak" you would get "Armweak,Paul,weak,44".

I hope the following code helps you:

```
filename     = "SampleFile.txt"
filename_new = filename.replace(".", "_new.")

search_term = "Smith"

with open(filename) as src, open(filename_new, 'w') as dst:

    for line in src:

        if line.startswith(search_term):

            items = line.split(",")
            items[4-1] = items[4-1].replace("old", "new")

            line = ",".join(items)

        dst.write(line)
```

If you work with a csv-file you should have a look at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

PS My files contain the following data (the filenames are not in the files!!!):

```
SampleFile.txt           SampleFile_new.txt

Adams,George,m,old,34    Adams,George,m,old,34
Adams,Tracy,f,old,32     Adams,Tracy,f,old,32
Smith,John,m,old,53      Smith,John,m,new,53
Man,Emily,w,old,44       Man,Emily,w,old,44
```